# dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Tags: apt, dpkg

The Software upto date Option automatically download the upgarde for GIMP.
but While installing its giving me the error. how to upgrade the same

---

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gimp
Suggested packages:
  gimp-help-en gimp-help libgimp-perl gimp-gap gimp-console
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gimp
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,388 kB of archives.
After this operation, 324 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 151157 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace gimp 2.6.11-2ubuntu4 (using .../gimp_2.7.4-2011102201~oo_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gimp ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.7.4-2011102201~oo_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-xmc', which is also in package gimp-plugin-registry 3.5.4-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.7.4-2011102201~oo_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a custom PPA for Gimp remove it.

Remove package `gimp-plugin-registry` and `gimp`

```
sudo apt-get remove gimp-plugin-registry gimp
```

Fix packages

```
sudo apt-get -f
```

Update Gimp package

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gimp gimp-plugin-registry
```

Install `gimp-plugin-registry` and `gimp`

```
sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry gimp
```

Comment: ---------------------------------
I tried to remove the package , but it seems all is interdependent
I am Getting Following Error
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.6.11-z) but 2.7.4-2011102201~oo is to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (<= 2.6.11-z) but 2.7.4-2011102201~oo is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: on running apt-get -f install I m again getting the same Error.

Comment: Have any gimp PPA's active at the moment?

Comment: nope.. I had just installed it day before yesterday..!!
today restarted my machine & then Software up-to-date told that updates are available install those so i just installed..

Comment: try to remove both packages, update and fix them and then try to install.

Comment: System is not allowing me to remove any package or install any package am stuck.
every i try to do that it tells run `apt-get -f install `
& on running it gives same error

Comment: try to run a `sudo apt-get clean` first of all to clear your cache.

Comment: it removed all  the file from cache..
then i  tried to remove both the package for gimp.
it gave following error & told to run `apt-get -f install`
`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp-gmic : Depends: gimp (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

on executing `apt-get -f install` 
it downloaded the package again & the same error.

Comment: they Thanks for helping..!!!
Yesterday i removed the PPA Repository & had shutdown my system.
Today when I restarted the System & executes `sudo apt-get -f install`. It automatically downloaded dependent file & removed all GIMP packages. 
Thanks for everything..!!!

Comment: Edited the answer to include information about the PPA, mark it complete if you agree with the steps taken.

Answer (score 1):

The `gimp` contains the file `/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-xmc` that is already installed by the package `gimp-plugin-registry`. AS a file can only be from one package you can't have both packages installed.

Judging from the version number your gimp package (but not gimp-plugin-registry) is from an unofficial package source. So you should either try find a package of `gimp-plugin-registry` that works with that gimp package or revert to the official gimp package.

Comment: I tried to remove the package , but it seems all is interdependent I am Getting Following Error

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.6.11-z) but 2.7.4-2011102201~oo is to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (<= 2.6.11-z) but 2.7.4-2011102201~oo is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

on running apt-get -f install  -- > Back to square 1 , same error

Answer (score 1):

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.7.4-2011102201~oo_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-xmc', which is also in package gimp-plugin-registry 3.5.4-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

Ok, this is a general answer rather that OP's problem.

This message indicates that some package is trying to overwrite a file that is included in another. **The safest solution is to remove one of the two packages.** In this example it could be either `gimp` or `gimp-plugin-registry`.

This is normally due to adding not so well maintained PPA's, since these problems are fixed by bots in the main repositories.