# Failed Firmware for Linux Kernel Update

Tags: kernel, pipe

I'm a bit new to this, while updating the firmware for Linux kernel drivers (1.79.14)
I encountered the following problem:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 193788 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace linux-firmware 1.79.1 (using .../linux-firmware_1.79.14_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-firmware ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.14_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu', which is also in package bt-dw1705-firmware 0.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.14_all.deb
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've already tried solution that was posted for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79930/dpkg-deb-error-subprocess-paste-was-killed-by-signal-broken-pipe) question
but the same problem still exists. (Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: The same happens to me, I'm on a Dell  Latitude 3540, with an Atheros wireless card, AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: Related: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/247054 (see last comment, I currently don't have time to check this and provide a complete answer, removing `bt-dw1705-firmware` and reconfiguring `linux-firmware` with dpkg should do the job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The cause

The reason why you get this error message is that the package `bt-dw1705-firmware` provides a firmware file that the `linux-firmware` package wants to overwrite or update.

The package management mechanisms of Linux operating systems are designed to prevent different packages from overwriting each others files and leave the system in an inconsistent state. That is why you get this error.

## Solution

The `bt-dw1705-firmware` [doesn't seem to be a Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=bt-dw1705-firmware) and therefore is probably not supported or maintained anymore, while `linux-firmware` clearly is.

You should remove `bt-dw1705-firmware` either with `sudo apt-get remove bt-dw1705-firmware` or if that doesn't work with `sudo dpkg --remove bt-dw1705-firmware` and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-firmware` afterwards.

Alternatively you could use `sudo dpkg --force-overwrite linux-firmware` according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/403361/40581). But this will probably cause the issue to re-appear as soon as `linux-firmware` is updated again.

The answer was approved by the OP, so it's safe to assume that the firmware file in `linux-firmware` works, no matter which solution you pick.